# Cannot benchmark DynamoDb using YCSB

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, benchmarking, ycsb

I need to use YCSB to benchmark DynamoDB and trying to use YCSB for the first time.

The dynamo provisioned throughput is 100 RCU and 50 WCUs. Following is the command I am executing:

```
./bin/ycsb load dynamodb -P dynamodb-binding/conf/dynamodb.properties -P workloads/workloada -threads 1 -target 40
```

The properties file has the endpoint (us-east-1), aws credentials etc. defined. I can run the ycsb shell with inserts:

```
./bin/ycsb shell dynamo
```

The table schema has only 1 field which is named: partition_key. Since dynamo is schemaless any column could be added by YCSB and should not be a problem.
But when I try to perform a load I get the following errors:

```
./bin/ycsb load dynamodb -P dynamodb-binding/conf/dynamodb.properties -P workloads/workloada -threads 1 -target 40

java -cp /opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/conf:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/conf:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/lib/core-0.12.0.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.4.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-api-gateway-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudfront-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-codecommit-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-codedeploy-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-codepipeline-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-config-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-datapipeline-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-devicefarm-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-directconnect-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-directory-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-ecr-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-ecs-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-efs-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-elasticache-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-emr-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-events-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-glacier-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-importexport-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-inspector-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-iot-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-logs-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-machinelearning-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-opsworks-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-rds-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-route53-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-sns-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-storagegateway-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-support-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-waf-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/aws-java-sdk-workspaces-1.10.48.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/dynamodb-binding-0.12.0.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/httpclient-4.3.6.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/httpcore-4.3.3.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/joda-time-2.8.1.jar:/opt/ycsb-0.12.0/dynamodb-binding/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.DynamoDBClient -P dynamodb-binding/conf/dynamodb.properties -P workloads/workloada -threads 1 -target 40 -load
YCSB Client 0.12.0
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.DynamoDBClient -P dynamodb-binding/conf/dynamodb.properties -P workloads/workloada -threads 1 -target 40 -load
Loading workload...
Starting test.
0 [Thread-1] INFO com.yahoo.ycsb.db.DynamoDBClient -dynamodb connection created with http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
DBWrapper: report latency for each error is false and specific error codes to track for latency are: []
435 [Thread-1] ERROR com.yahoo.ycsb.db.DynamoDBClient -com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key partition_key in the item (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: BOJ5PRDH5N2H40TDH04ERN47BBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
Error inserting, not retrying any more. number of attempts: 1Insertion Retry Limit: 0
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 934.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 0.0
[TOTAL_GCS_PS_Scavenge], Count, 1.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_PS_Scavenge], Time(ms), 8.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%PS_Scavenge], Time(%), 0.8565310492505354
[TOTAL_GCS_PS_MarkSweep], Count, 0.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_PS_MarkSweep], Time(ms), 0.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME%PS_MarkSweep], Time(%), 0.0
[TOTAL_GCs], Count, 1.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME], Time(ms), 8.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME%], Time(%), 0.8565310492505354
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1.0
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 1.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 1.0
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 1.0
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 1.0
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 1.0
[INSERT], Operations, 0.0
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), NaN
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 9.223372036854776E18
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 0.0
[INSERT], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 0.0
[INSERT], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 0.0
[INSERT], Return=ERROR, 1
[INSERT-FAILED], Operations, 1.0
[INSERT-FAILED], AverageLatency(us), 428928.0
[INSERT-FAILED], MinLatency(us), 428800.0
[INSERT-FAILED], MaxLatency(us), 429055.0
[INSERT-FAILED], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 429055.0
[INSERT-FAILED], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 429055.0
```

When we load data by YCSB workloada, what kind of data is loaded in the DB (basically what is the source of that data). Could anyone please guide me to understand as to what I am missing?

~Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. It was due to the fact that I chose the name of the partition key of dynamo as "partition_key". I changed it to something else and it worked fine.

Thanks.